# Can Debezium MySQL Connector route data change event to different topic by event's operation type?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

There are three types of data change event that Debezium support:

- insert
- delete
- update

I've known that there is an `op` field in Debezium published message's payload that identify the event type, but i wonder that is there anyway that i can route these three types of data change event to different Kafka topic by the operation type, like SMT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Single Message Transform

As you suggest, Single Message Transform is a good option to use here. Debezium have a transform currently in beta called [`ContentBasedRouter`](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/configuration/content-based-routing.html) with which you can code the routing using languages including Groovy.

### ksqlDB

You can do this with ksqlDB:

```sql
-- Declare source topic from Debezium as ksqlDB stream
CREATE STREAM ORDERS WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='asgard.demo.ORDERS', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');

-- Create three streams (backed by Kafka topics) based on the op-type
CREATE STREAM ORDERS_UPDATES AS SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE OP='u';
CREATE STREAM ORDERS_DELETES AS SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE OP='d';
CREATE STREAM ORDERS_CREATES AS SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE OP='c';
```

View the data

```sql
ksql> SHOW TOPICS;

 Kafka Topic                           | Partitions | Partition Replicas
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ORDERS_CREATES                        | 1          | 1
 ORDERS_DELETES                        | 1          | 1
 ORDERS_UPDATES                        | 1          | 1
```

Check the counts

```sql
ksql> SELECT OP,COUNT(*) AS EVENTS FROM ORDERS GROUP BY OP EMIT CHANGES;
+-------+----------+
|OP     |EVENTS    |
+-------+----------+
|u      |3         |
|c      |502       |
|d      |5         |

ksql> SELECT 'ORDERS_UPDATES' AS TOPIC_NAME ,COUNT(*) AS EVENT_COUNT 
        FROM ORDERS_UPDATES GROUP BY 'ORDERS_UPDATES' EMIT CHANGES LIMIT 1 ;
+----------------+-------------+
|TOPIC_NAME      |EVENT_COUNT  |
+----------------+-------------+
|ORDERS_UPDATES  |3            |
Limit Reached
Query terminated

ksql> SELECT 'ORDERS_CREATES' AS TOPIC_NAME ,COUNT(*) AS EVENT_COUNT 
        FROM ORDERS_CREATES GROUP BY 'ORDERS_CREATES' EMIT CHANGES LIMIT 1 ;
+----------------+-------------+
|TOPIC_NAME      |EVENT_COUNT  |
+----------------+-------------+
|ORDERS_CREATES  |503          |
Limit Reached
Query terminated

ksql> SELECT 'ORDERS_DELETES' AS TOPIC_NAME ,COUNT(*) AS EVENT_COUNT 
        FROM ORDERS_DELETES GROUP BY 'ORDERS_DELETES' EMIT CHANGES LIMIT 1 ;
+----------------+-------------+
|TOPIC_NAME      |EVENT_COUNT  |
+----------------+-------------+
|ORDERS_DELETES  |5            |
Limit Reached
Query terminated
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the content-based router, @Robin. user8510613, one important thing to keep in mind here is that there are no ordering guarantees across topics. I.e. it might be an UPDATE event is consumed before the INSERT of the same database record. Typically, all records for one key should go into the same partion/topic which avoids these potential ordering issues.

Comment: @Gunnar Thanks for your hint, i am using Hive as sink system, and Confluent HDFS Sink Connector for writing the data into Hive. Single record level update/delete is not considered as best practise in Hive world, so i tend to use a batch style to merge the update/delete event into the insert table. I sincerely desire for better advice.